# Word for someone who speaks less but has positive connotation

Tags: vocabulary, connotations

I understand there are words like *Taciturn* that have same meaning but can be used to compliment someone. *Taciturn* seems to have negative connotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Reserved](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reserved)

> 1: restrained in words and actions

[Thoughtful](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thoughtful)

> 1a: absorbed in thought : MEDITATIVE

[Pensive](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pensive)

> 1: musingly or dreamily thoughtful

[Quiet](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quiet)

> 1a: marked by little or no motion or activity : CALM

[Introverted](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/introverted)

> : having or suggesting the characteristics of an introvert
>   especially : possessing a reserved or shy nature typically with an inclination to solitude

(Introvert still has some negative connotation but it has been shifting in a more positive direction as we understand the benefits and strengths of an introvert.)

These are all words I use as a teacher to describe my quieter students in a positive and respectful way.